# Weird behaviour of preferredStatusBarStyle

Tags: ios, xcode, uinavigationcontroller

I'm trying to set **.lightContent** for all view controllers more or less globally. It can't be set, so the only way to do that - overriding.

My applications structure is root tabBar with navigationControllers in each tab. It seems to me, that if viewControllers don't override **preferredStatusBarStyle** app will use the navigationController's property if provided.

So, I added subclass with overriding, but my assumption is true only for first tab - everywhere else it's dark (default value).

Is my assumption is incorrect and I can't set it like this, or I have some problem?

Comment: if you want changes in every controller , you can do it directly in appDelegate.

Comment: @TusharSharma, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out, that I can set **View controller-based status bar appearance** to NO and have global setting in Target Settings